# Editing a class file in jar

Tags: java, eclipse, class, jar, zip

I know that editing a class file in jar can be easily done by first converting jar to a zip file, then extracting the zip and finally decompiling the class file in order to edit it. After editing, I do all the above steps in reverse and finally replace the new jar file with the old one. 
I tried the above, but it seems that after replacing the edited jar file with the new one, my java project in eclipse doesn't recognize the jar file! First, I thought the problem is the way I decompile the class file in jar; but later I found out it is not and I have the same problem even without decompiling the class file and editing it. 
So if I have a simple jar file and convert it to a zip file and then without any further steps I convert it back to the jar file I don't have any problem. But if I have a simple jar file and try to convert it to a zip file and then extract it; again I compress it back to zip and convert it to jar my eclipse cannot recognize the jar file! 
 So to me the problem is when I compress the folder back to a zip file! What could be the problem here? Is it the compression tool that I use?

Comment: A jar file is a zip file (just with a different extension). There's no conversion required

Comment: You dont want to use "zip" tools. Just learn how to run the "jar" tool on the command line.

Comment: What do you mean by cernverting to a zip? Just use 7-zip.org, open the jar, replace the class and that's it. You should not use Windows buildin zip, because this implementation is not perfect.

Comment: Side note: why do you want to do that in the first place? (what I mean: you understand that sometimes, the licences of 3rd party libraries ... do not allow you to decompile/modify stuff?)

Answer (score 0):

At the time of creating zip file instead of zipping the out side folder, make sure you select individual file and then make zip of the file.

I guess if your test.jar file contains abc.class and xyz.class but after you making the new test.jar files it would be something like this:

> test.jar --contains-> test(Folder) --contains-> abc.class, xyz.class //This is why it might not be recognized
>
> test.jar --contains-> abc.class, xyz.class //Try to make like your old format

@digipenKH suggested simple way to do the same: just use 7-zip.org, open the jar, replace the class and that's it.